# How can I take a list of strings and find files who name matches a string in the list?

Tags: python, bash, macos, command-line

I have a list of 600+ numbers, and a directory of 50,000+ files. All of the files are named like this:

```
99574404682_0.jpg
99574404682_1.jpg
99574437307_0.gif
99574437307_1.gif
99574437307_2.gif
99574449752.jpg
99574457597.jpg
99581722007.gif
```

I want to copy any file that has a name that matches a number in the list, up to the underscore, and copy to a new directory.

For example if my list contains:

```
99574404682
99574449752
99581722007
```

Then the files:

```
99574404682_0.jpg
99574404682_1.jpg
99574449752.jpg
99581722007.gif
```

would be copied to a new directory. I am on a Mac using bash 3.2. I am thinking something like python is what I need to use because the list is too large for grep or find but I am not sure. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some code which has tried?

Comment: A quick code: `while read number; do cp /source/directory/$number[._]* /dest/dir 2>/dev/null; done < number_list_filename` (Assuming that the numbers are one per line.)

Comment: Thank you! I’ll give this a try tonight.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate through two lists taking item from one based on `startswith` condition:

```
files_lst = ['99574404682_0.jpg', '99574404682_1.jpg', '99574437307_0.gif', '99574437307_1.gif', '99574437307_2.gif', '99574449752.jpg', '99574457597.jpg', '99581722007.gif']

lst = [99574404682, 99574449752, 99581722007]

for x in files_lst:
    for y in lst:
        if x.startswith(str(y)):
            print(x)

# 99574404682_0.jpg
# 99574404682_1.jpg
# 99574449752.jpg
# 99581722007.gif
```

This gets all files that starts with numbers provided in `lst`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`shutil.copy()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy) to copy your files over from a source to a destination.

```
from shutil import copy

from os import listdir
from os import makedirs

from os.path import abspath
from os.path import exists
from os.path import splitext

filenames = {'99574404682', '99574449752', '99581722007'}

src_path = # your files
dest_path = # where you want to put them

# make the destination if it doesn't exist
if not exists(dest_path):
    makedirs(dest_path)

# go over each file in src_path
for file in listdir(src_path):

    # If underscore in file
    if "_" in file:
        prefix, *_ = file.split("_")

    # otherwise treat as normal file
    else:
        prefix, _ = splitext(file)

    # only copy if prefix exist in above set
    if prefix in filenames:
        copy(abspath(file), dest_path)
```

Which results in the following files in `dest_path`:

```
99574404682_0.jpg  
99574404682_1.jpg  
99574449752.jpg  
99581722007.gif
```

I'm not really an expert in bash, but you can try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a arr=("99574404682" "99574449752" "99581722007")

## Example directories, you can change these
src_path="$PWD/*"
dest_path="$PWD/src"

if [ ! -d "$dest_path" ]; then
    mkdir $dest_path
fi

for f1 in $src_path; do 
    filename=$(basename $f1)
    prefix="${filename%.*}"
    IFS='_' read -r -a array <<< $prefix

    for f2 in "${arr[@]}"; do
        if [ "${array[0]}" == "$f2" ]; then
            cp $f1 $dest_path
        fi
    done
done
```

Answer (score 1):

using os module and shutil module in python

```
import os
import shutil
```

and you can prepare a list contains the match pattern likes

```
match_pattern=['99574404682','99574449752','99581722007']
```

then use os.listdir() to get a list which contains the file name in source directory

```
files_in_source_dir=os.listdir(source_directory_path)
```

at last copy the matching files

```
for file in files_in_source_dir:
  if file.split('.')[0] in match_pattern: #using split('.')[0] to get filename without extend name
    shutil.copyfile(source_directory_path+file,target_directory_path+file)
```